# Searching for multiple tags has no way to require all of them to be present in new-nav

Tags: support, status-norepro, design, new-nav

Entering multiple tags with the syntax `[tag-one] [tag-two]` in the search bar takes me to the question page filtered such that any question with either tag will appear. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/?show=all&sort=newest&layout=expanded&tagFilter=list&tags=bus%20usb). I discovered this behavior when a meta link from a burninate request returned manifestly useless results by default.

There is no obvious way, syntactically or from the GUI, of forcing an AND search with these tags; sticking "and" in the string appears to search for that literal string, although it does switch away from question-page mode to search-result mode.

Answer (score 3):

There is a toggle on the right for this purpose:

[image: toggle]

So... there is a way. Although for now, this combination of tabs, dropdowns and toggles that keep winking in and out of existence makes me yearn for the good old days of command line interfaces.

Comment: Hmm. Given that I *did* notice, and set, the expanded/summary toggle just above that, I don't know why that apparently wasn't visible to me.

Comment: I got a laugh out of "yearn for the good old days of command line interfaces".  It does seem as though, in the 40 odd years since the first GUI, we have yet to discover an interface that is really intuitive and that can be expanded to fit dozens of unanticipated situations.  Or worse, we have discovered dozens of such interfaces, mutually contradictory, and no way of extinguishing the ones that aren't good enough.