# Filtering questions by multiple tags doesn't work with the new navigation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-nav, tag-search

This is not about [selecting the "all" option in the new navigation when filtering for multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256984/159034), it's about the old tag links for filtering questions by multiple tags.

You used to be able to [filter questions by multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9797/filtering-questions-by-specifying-multiple-tags) by having a url like

```
/questions/tagged/first+second
```

Which would trigger a search for `[first] [second]`, which meant that only questions with both [first](/questions/tagged/first) **and** [second](/questions/tagged/second) would be displayed.

In the new navigation though, this request will perform the same search with one small change: by default, the questions will be filtered down to questions containing [first](/questions/tagged/first) **or** [second](/questions/tagged/second). This means that any existing links for filtering questions by multiple tags will no longer work when the new navigation is released to everyone.

[I confirmed in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3514811#3514811) that this behavior still happens for those without the new navigation. Those with the new navigation cannot test this as an anonymous user as [only a single tag search is allowed there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243960/multiple-tags-search-broken-when-searching-as-anonymous-user).

Comment: There's a convo in SO's meta about the opposite problem: Searching by a single tag is either very slow or not working at all for some users https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295649/single-tag-pages-wont-load-but-works-if-more-than-one-used

Comment: @Sklivvz I think this is now [tag:status-completed] with the latest set of updates to the navigation.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed with the new release candidate.