# "Related tags" are AWOL in the new nav

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-nav, related-tags

It seems that they [used to be there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257552/the-related-tags-no-longer-filters-by-both-tags-in-the-new-navigation) (despite being broken), but i can't find them right now.

When i go to [[javascript]](https://stackoverflow.com/?tags=javascript) on SO, it's missing this beautiful sidebar:

> [image: related tags]

Please bring it back.

What maybe could be done is when you click edit (at the top, to change the tag search), it could suggest the top several related tags. This should be done in tandem with [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257525/filtering-questions-by-multiple-tags-doesnt-work-with-the-new-navigation?lq=1).

Answer (score 6):

I just discovered that the related tags (as well as the question count) are missing if you are not using the expanded list. **The short term fix is to switch to the expanded list by clicking the “Show excerpts” button** whenever you need related tags.

[image: annotated screenshot]

You'll notice that [PythonMaster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/278543/pythonmaster) appears to be using the expanded list. This also explains why it's "random" and only affects certain people: not everyone uses the expanded list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yes it should even though I still have it...:

[image]

Seemingly this hits random users who are testing the new navigation system. Some are affected and some are not. The fact that the groups of users are random makes this problem a little suspicious here. I think it is just a coincidence that it targets random groups of users like how the SE system chooses random groups of <del>victims</del> users to become testers.

There is probably a bug in the code that chooses its targets in groups, probably the same groups SE chooses...

Comment: See [Kevin's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259601) answer.

Comment: Wow. Sweet and simple. I'm destroyed...