# Searching for tags is inconsistent with new navigation

Tags: feature-request, new-nav

There are currently a couple of ways to search for multiple tags:

- You do "show all", then filter "custom tags" and then add a few tags. This will by default result in a query for: **Any** of the tags searched for, sorted by **recent activity**.
- You will notice that in the top-right corner it will show `[tag1] [tag2]` in the search bar. Searching for this yields results with **any** of the tags searched for, sorted by **newest first**.
- If you search for the tags, plus a keyword, this yields results with **all** of the tags and the keywords, sorted by an unknown property.

This is confusing and inconsistent, and I would like to see similar queries to yield similar results.

Related: [Searching for multiple tags has no way to require all of them to be present in new-nav](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256984/searching-for-multiple-tags-has-no-way-to-require-all-of-them-to-be-present-in-n) (but for some reason status-norepro)

Related: [Filtering questions by multiple tags doesn't work with the new navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257525/filtering-questions-by-multiple-tags-doesnt-work-with-the-new-navigation) (but it only addresses part of the problem)

---

I would suggest that searching for `[tag1] [tag2]` would yield results with **all** of the tags, either sorted by **recent activity** or the unknown property of regular searches.

I would suggest that new keywords are introduced for the searches and clicking "any" or "all" in the new navigation interface will change the search query from `[tag1] [tag2]` to `[tag1] or [tag2]` or `[tag1] [tag2] mode:any`.

Similarly, new keywords can be introduced for other navigation options that currently enter something into the search bar, but actually searching for that would yield vastly different results. What is entered in the search bar can then be changed to something that will yield the same results.